# refactor PHP code to get data from local functions

Tags: php, object

I've made some code to create form fields, now I have issues where i need to replicate switch statement for multi step forms, and I feel whenever I need to replicate code, I'm doing it wrong;

```
    // (var) HTML Content to be returned
    $content = '';

    /**
     * Output Single form fields
     */
    if (isset($_form['single'])) {

        // Get templates and content for the single step form, based on form type
        foreach ($_form['single'] as $_value) {

            switch ($_value[0]) {
                case 'select':
                    $content .= $f_select($_value);
                    break;
                case 'heading':
                    $content .= $f_heading($_value);
                    break;
                case 'input':
                    $content .= $f_input($_value);
                    break;
                case 'date':
                    $content .= $f_date($_value);
                    break;
                case 'textarea':
                    $content .= $f_textarea($_value);
                    break;
                case 'info':
                    $content .= $f_info($_value);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
```

Any idea of how to refactor this so i could access data from variable functions from switch statement, so that i can do checks for  example if (isset($_form['multi'][0,1...])) {

Comment: thinking, maybe its possible to  merge $_form['single']  and $_form['multi'][0,1...] if they exists, and do additional checks in for each loop, as a new combined object